# Comment lines in .sln file

Tags: sln-file

I'm trying to comment some lines in .sln file temporarly, but I receive error: 
"**The selected file is a solution file, but appears to be corrupted and cannot be opened**"

According to [this blog](http://milagaia.blogspot.com/2012/02/solution-file-sln-comments.html) comments are done by "**#**", but when I comment out every line in GlobalSection (section about Team Foundation Server source control binding) I get above error. Is there any other way to comment out lines in .sln ?

EDIT - section of which I want to comment out:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 2
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4BA58AB2-18FA-4D8F-95F4-32FFDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://oxy:8080/tfs/projects
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = Accounts\\Accounts.vbproj
        SccProjectName1 = Accounts
        SccLocalPath1 = Accounts
EndGlobalSection
```

I tried this, but not working:

```
#  GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
#           SccNumberOfProjects = 2
#           SccEnterpriseProvider = {4BA58AB2-18FA-4D8F-95F4-32FFDF27D184C}
#           SccTeamFoundationServer = http://oxy:8080/tfs/projects
#           SccLocalPath0 = .
#           SccProjectUniqueName1 = Accounts\\Accounts.vbproj
#           SccProjectName1 = Accounts
#           SccLocalPath1 = Accounts
#    EndGlobalSection
```

P.S.: I tried a single line comment using "**#**" - that works. And removing whole section also works. But I don't want to delete It, just comment It.

Comment: Hi, please show us your code. Maybe the comment succeed but you comment out something important.

Comment: @Baruch, there is no code. It's a simple question on how do I comment .sln file. However I will put something in edited question, looks like another downvote for no reason...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is an official definition of comments in the `.sln` file. It depends on the **parser**.

In principle, a `.sln` file is a declarative file, based on the keywords (`ProjectSection`, `EndGlobalSection`) and the end-line char. I don't see a uniform format description.

### MSBuild

So we don't know how *Visual Studio* reads the `.sln` file, but you can see in the [msbuild code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Build/Construction/Solution/SolutionFile.cs#L517-L541) that any line that doesn't start with one of the **const words** will not enter to the object:

```cs
while ((str = ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (str.StartsWith("Project(", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        ParseProject(str);
    }
    else if (str.StartsWith("GlobalSection(NestedProjects)", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        ParseNestedProjects();
    }
    else if (str.StartsWith("GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        ParseSolutionConfigurations();
    }
    else if (str.StartsWith("GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms)", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        rawProjectConfigurationsEntries = ParseProjectConfigurations();
    }
    else if (str.StartsWith("VisualStudioVersion", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        _currentVisualStudioVersion = ParseVisualStudioVersion(str);
    }
    else
    {
        // No other section types to process at this point, so just ignore the line
        // and continue.
    }
}
```

### Visual Studio

> According to this blog comments are done by "#"

That is not accurate. You can add **lines** with **any text** where you want, without the `#`, and the file will stay correct.

So, in *Visual Studio*, you currently don't know the official format, but you need to "break" the current format.

You can try changing the **keywords**, such as adding a letter to them at the beginning.
From what I've tried, special characters (such as `#`, `%`) don't break your keywords.

Comment: thanks for response. Well looks like I can't do what I was hoping for :(

Comment: @Lucy82 I agree ... right now. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2766) in the documentation, hoping that the subject would come up.

Comment: thanks again. I hope that question is going to be answered someday.